# The php value from the database is not being passed when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I got most of my php and jquery working but I am currently stuggling on one thing which is how do I pass a db value in a while loop on button click to the jquery? At present nothing is being printed

```
<?php
...

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        print
        "<div class='item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4'>".
            "<div class='row'>".
                "<div class='col-xs-10'>".
                     "<p class='list-group-item-text'>".
                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr'>".
                    "<button id='button' class='btn btn-success'>Calculate</button>".
                "</div>".
            "</div>".
        "</div>";
    }
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "#button", function(){
        var name = '<?php echo($row['name']); ?>';
        alert(name);
    });
</script>
```

Say there are like seven of these boxes and the user clicks on the fourth one - how do I get that row name, like pass that to the jquery?

Comment: Each button needs a unique id. All ids in html have to be unique.

Comment: Sorry mate, how do I do that? I am completely new to web development

Comment: `var name = '<?php echo($row['name']); ?>';` – that won’t output anything (apart from an error message, if you have them enabled – which you should go do right now; they are a valuable tool to figure out what you’re doing wrong during development). Your while loop ends, because `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will return NULL after the last record has been processed – so you are trying to output the `name` entry of NULL here, which of course doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we need to change a few things. Every element in the HTML DOM needs a unique id. If more than one element has the same id, the machines get very confused. This is understandable, since you're saying hey pay attention to the button with the id #button! And it's like, which one? There are 7. We can add a unique id to each button during the loop by using the id from the current row the loop is fetching from the db. NB that in HTML, element ids cannot begin with a number. That's why I used button-45,etc.

We can also change the listener to listen to a *class* of buttons instead of a specific button - that way if any button on the page with the right class gets clicked, the listener hears it. Using jQuery you can also add data directly to the element, and retrieve is using .data().  I've provided two variables in the javascript so you can see the results of each approach.

```
<?php
...

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        print
        "<div class='item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4'>".
            "<div class='row'>".
                "<div class='col-xs-10'>".
                     "<p class='list-group-item-text'>".
                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr-".$row['id']."'>".
                    "<button id='button-".$row['id']."' data-id='".$row['id']."' class='btn btn-success btn_calc'>Calculate</button>".
                "</div>".
            "</div>".
        "</div>";
    }
    $i++;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".btn_calc", function(){
        var id_only = $(this).data('id'); //this gets us the id
        //you can log values to the console, then right-click and inspect to see the results:
        console.log("id_only = ",id_only);
        //this gets the text into a variable
        var text = $('#usr-'+id_only).val();
        console.log("text = ", text);
        //alert(text);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: isnt this javascript and not jquery?

Comment: So jQuery is javascript, it's just a specific library built up out of it.  You had written the event listener as a jQuery listener, so I assumed you were using jQuery. Is that not the case?  Do you have a link to a version of jQuery in your <head> or no?

Comment: Yeah I am using jquery. I have two problems though. 1. With your approach, what happens if the name at that button has an id of `45`? I am getting these values from a database. 2. It prints an alert button_2 as opposed to an valid id like say 45

Comment: Oh, gotcha. So can we get that id in the loop by using $row['id']?  Is that how it's going to appear?

Comment: Yeah that is what i am trying to do lol :P. I don't know how to do that

Comment: thanks, does this also get the value from the edit textfield just out of interest?

Comment: It does not. To get that, you would need to do something like `var text = $('#usr-45').val();`

Comment: or would it be `var text = $('#usr-$row['id']').val();` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108676/discussion-between-larsanders-and-benj-mikesozery).

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        print
        "<div class='item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4'>".
            "<div class='row'>".
                "<div class='col-xs-10'>".
                     "<p class='list-group-item-text'>".
                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='usr_" . $i . "'>".
                    "<button id='button_" . $i . "' class='btn btn-success'>Calculate</button>".
                "</div>".
            "</div>".
        "</div>";

    $i ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that you are trying to pass data in STRING FORMAT.
In your script you pass the $row out of while loop so it doesn't pass anything useful for you. If you have more than one button you can't use ID ATTRIBUTE but you have to use CLASS. Set a data-id attribute so you can pass the value from the database and set an ID to the input so you can take its value also. Try this:

```
<?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            print
            "<div class='item  col-xs`-4 col-lg-4'>".
                "<div class='row'>".
               "<div class='col-xs-10'>".
                 "<p class='list-group-item-text'>".
                "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='input-" . $row["id"] . "'>".
                "<button data-id='". $row["id"] . "' class='mybutton btn btn-success'>Calculate</button>".
            "</div>".
        "</div>".
    "</div>";
    }
 }

 ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".mybutton").on("click", function(){
        var myid = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var myinput = $('#input-'+myid).val();
        alert("MY ID IS: " + myid);
        alert("MY INPUT VALUE IS: " + myinput);
    });
});
 </script>
```